# get_upload_preferences() is deprecated - any idea how to fix this?

Tags: add-on-development

I've got a custom fieldtype I need to upgrade for EE 2.5.5 - It uses the Tools model, which was deprecated in EE 2.2. Here's the code that's coughing up errors in the developer log:

> $upload_prefs = $this->EE->tools_model->get_upload_preferences($this->EE->session->userdata('group_id'));
>           foreach ($upload_prefs->result() as $row) $upload_dirs[$row->id] = $row->name;

And here's the error:

> The system has detected an add-on that is using outdated code that may stop working or cause issues with the system. What does this mean?
>   Deprecated function get_upload_preferences() called in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\EE\system\expressionengine\third_party\custom_fieldtype\ft.custom_fieldtype.php on line 272.
>   Deprecated since 2.2. Use File_upload_preferences_model::get_file_upload_preferences() instead.

I've tried replacing tools_model->get_upload_preferences with file_upload_preferences_model->get_file_upload_preferences, but that gives us this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\EE\system\expressionengine\third_party\custom_fieldtype\ft.custom_fieldtype.php on line 273

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Again I am trying to resolve your problem :)

You should update your code like:

```
$this->EE->load->model('file_upload_preferences_model');
$upload_prefs = $this->EE->file_upload_preferences_model->get_file_upload_preferences($this->EE->session->userdata('group_id'));

/***
$upload_prefs itself an array having all the upload preferences.
***/

foreach ($upload_prefs as $row)
{
$upload_dirs[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}
```

I hope, it would help. Plz post your further comments if it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like it's working, one more problem though - I've got a couple of lines causing an error message: `$directory_info = $this->EE->file_upload_preferences_model->get_file_upload_preferences($group_id, $upload_location);
    $server_path = $directory_info->row('server_path');` and the error: `http://127.0.0.1/EE/admin.php?S=64003fd21507ab78df83e67007b714fdb91cf930&D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=2`

Comment: @ninjachicken1: I could share the error message text. In your comment, you shared the CP link your localhost ;) .

Comment: Doh! I think it may be fixed now as I'm not getting the error anymore, I'm now testing it.